# node_modules management in nuxt dockerize app

Tags: docker, nuxt.js

I'm trying to find the best way to work with a Nuxt dockerized application when it comes to the management of the node_modules folder and best practices ref. install new dependencies and dev-dependencies. At the moment the node_modules folder just lives in the docker container and it's being ignored by .dockerignore file (which as far as I know is a good practice in terms of performance).

The part where this process gets confusing to me is when I try to find the best way to install new dev / dependencies when I need them. How to do that ? Should I just add them in the package.json file and re-built the container ? Should I create a local node_modules folder ?, Should I mount the node_modules directory as a volume ?.

At the moment for example I'm testing with Prettier and even when I have the module in my package.json and lock json file Prettier it's shouting at me that the node module is not installed locally (which make sense because I don't have a node_modules folder, since it's being ignored by .dockerignore).

```
["INFO" - 09:53:58] Extension Name: esbenp.prettier-vscode.
["INFO" - 09:53:58] Extension Version: 9.19.0.
["INFO" - 09:53:58] Attempted to determine module path from /Users/myname/sites/www.xyz.com/frontend
["ERROR" - 09:53:58] Failed to load module. If you have prettier or plugins referenced in package.json, ensure you have run `npm install`
["ERROR" - 09:53:58] Cannot find module 'prettier' from '/Users/myname/sites/www.xyz.com/frontend'
```

This is my Dockerfile:

```
ARG NODE_ENV
ENV NODE_ENV $NODE_ENV

WORKDIR /home/app

RUN apk update && apk add glu python3 make g++

COPY package*.json ./

# update npm to the latest version
RUN npm install -g npm

# Install dependencies based on the environment
RUN if [ "${ENVIRONMENT}" = "dev" ]; then \
  npm install; \
else \
  npm ci; \
fi

RUN npx browserslist@latest --update-db

COPY . .

# Copy tranlations from correct phrase image (depending on dockertag/branch)
COPY --from=phrase /locales/* /home/app/assets/locales/phrase/

ENV NODE_OPTIONS="--max_old_space_size=8192"

RUN npm run nuxt:build

CMD ["npm", "run", "nuxt:start"]
```

Long story short just wondering if there's any Best practices around this topic since I have failed to find a solution that makes sense to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker's standard model is that an image contains an application and all of the libraries needed to run it.  Consider an image like `postgres`, for example: it depends on some (C) shared libraries, but these are included inside the image; you don't need an extra volume or mount to provide storage for its libraries, they're just part of the image.

The reverse of this is that, yes, if you change the application source or library depedencies, you must rebuild the image.  This would be a routine step for developers used to working in compiled languages (Go, Rust, Java, C++, ...) and even in your Dockerfile this causes the `npm run nuxt:build` step to be re-run as well.

So: if you change `package.json`, run `npm install` to update `package-lock.json`, test locally, and then re-run `docker build` to make a new image.  Don't do anything with volumes here.  If you're mounting volumes over your application in the image, delete those volumes: the old libraries in a `node_modules` volume will overwrite what you updated in `package.json`.

Comment: Many thanks David. Just to be sure If I understood your approach. When I need a new package I have to run npm i locally (hence create a node_modules folder) test locally and then re-run docker build to make a new image ?

Comment: The host `node_modules` folder isn't especially important, but you will find it much easier to run unit tests, debug, and iterate on your code in a host Node environment.

Comment: Sorry If I'm asking something funny here (my exp. with full dockerize apps is short). So in the case of prettier for example I DO have to install it locally to make it work, the reason I'm saying this is because some answers points in the direction of " the local development environment on your machine is being referenced instead of the Docker container" the implication being you dont need a local node-modules folder to make it work, which is confusing to me based on your answer (the node_modules not being specially important).

Comment: I'm suggesting you will have two copies of `node_modules` _and that's fine_.  For day-to-day work use Node directly on the host, `npm run test`, `npm run dev`, use tools like Nodemon, but completely ignore Docker.  For integration testing and deployment, _then_ build a Docker image.  It will have its own copy of the (built) application code and its own library tree.